# How can I automatically run a google script function when a worksheet is activated?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have some function in google script that I would like to run when a user activate a work sheets. Since I am new in google script, I don't know how to start. I have search on google, but have no luck.

Anyone know, please help.

Let say I want to change the value of the cell A1 to 1000 when sheet1 is activated. I have a function as bellow:

```
  function ChangeCellVal(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var selCell=1000;
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(selCell);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try checking [`Class SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder)

> *onOpen()*
>
> Specifies a trigger that will fire when the spreadsheet is opened.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
.forSpreadsheet(sheet)
.onOpen()
.create();
```

I hope it helps.